# Can I override dojo/store/JsonRest API methods?

Tags: javascript, dojo

[Dojo dojo/store/JsonRest API Reference](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html)

Please look at the [Method and RESTful Mapping Section](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#id6)

It's written there that my server should follow RFC 2616 to interact with the store. Can I use different implementation by overriding the standard method somehow? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the JsonRest Store to allow a custom request object and overrides its methods, I've customize it and using this one in  my project. I put it in separate CutomizeJSonRestStore.js file

```
   require([
            "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore", "dojo/store/JsonRest",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/store/Cache",
        ], function (declare, parser, ready, ObjStore, JsonRest, Memory, Cache) {
        declare("ServerSideStore", [ObjStore], {
            constructor: function(args) {
                /* jason source that will talks with server, set sort parametere to be read from server to know to sort according to what*/
                jasonRest = JsonRest({
                        target : this.target,
                        sortParam : "sortParam"
                    });



                /* cach store to make calls at cleint side if possible */
                cacheStore = new Cache(jasonRest, new Memory());
                this.objectStore = cacheStore;
                declare.safeMixin(this, args);
            },

            /*
                send request to server side to update an item
            */
            onSet : function (item, attribute, old, value) {
                dojo.xhrPost({
                    url : this.target + "?rsourceRequest=update&attributeParam=" + attribute + "&newValueParam=" + value,
                    postData : dojo.toJson(item),
                    handleAs : "json",
                    headers : {
                        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
                    },
                });
            },

            /*
                send request to server side to create new item
            */
            onNew: function(newItem, parentInfo) {
                dojo.xhrPost({
                    url : this.target + "?rsourceRequest=create&attributeParam",
                    postData : dojo.toJson(item),
                    handleAs : "json",
                    headers : {
                        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
                    },
                });
            },

            /*
                send request to server side to delete an item
            */
            onDelete: function(deletedItem) {
                dojo.xhrPost({
                    url : this.target + "?rsourceRequest=delete",
                    postData : dojo.toJson(item),
                    handleAs : "json",
                    headers : {
                        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
                    },
                });
            }

        });

    });
```

[dojo-jsonreststore more here](http://bestpractice.tumblr.com/post/4926210403/dojo-jsonreststore)
 [DOJO-JSON REST](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsonreststore/)

Comment: I figured I could just copy JsonRest.js.uncompressed and make a new module based on it. Thanks for the answer!